# Why does Tkinter Scrolledtext widget ignores whitespace in my case?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

[The problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJh0U.jpg) is that that i have a output which has to be shown in text format so I inserted the output in the Scrolledtext widget but here, the widget seems to ignore whitespaces, whereas when I just literally copied the text from Scrolledtext widget and pasted it in the windows notepad, the whitespaces are shown. I want the output in scrolledtext widget to be as it is in the notepad, what's wrong here?

Comment: You need to use a fixed-width font.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much. I has Segoe UI set as font in the Scrolledtext, now i changed it to Consolas and it works. I didn't thought it to be a font problem.